# TypeError: document.getElementById(...)[0] is undefined

Tags: javascript

Ok, guys. I'm not sure why this doesn't work. Following an example the teacher gave us and as far as I can tell, everything is the same except for the function and variable names... Using an external JavaScript file, Dreamweaver says there's no syntax errors or anything else of the sort but debugger on Firefox says `TypeError: document.getElementById(...)[0] is undefined...` which I'm not exactly sure why but here is my code:

**JavaScript**:

```
var caveboyanim = new Array(6);
var curCaveBoy = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    caveboyanim[i] = new Image();

    caveboyanim[i].src = "images/caveboy" + i + ".png";
}

function caveboyanimation() {
    if (curCaveBoy == 5)
        curCaveBoy = 0;
    else ++curCaveBoy;
    document.getElementById("caveboy")[0].src = caveboyanim[curCaveBoy].src;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<body onLoad="setInterval('caveboyanimation()', 1000);">

<img src="images/caveboy0.png" id="caveboy"  alt="Image of a cave boy">

</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove the `[0]` from:

```
document.getElementById("caveboy")[0].src = caveboyanim[curCaveBoy].src;
```

The index 0 is used with jQuery objects to get "real" document element. But you are not using JQuery here so it's not needed.

Comment: TY!!! was getting really frustrated :) now I can get back to building my casino splash page :)

Answer (score 3):

The return of `document.getElementById()` is not an array. Use:

```
document.getElementById("caveboy")
```

Comment: To elaborate, it's called `getElementById`, not `getElementsById` (note it's singular, not plural), which is different from, for example, `getElementsByTagName`. This makes sense, because you can only have one ID on a page.

Answer (score 1):

It's not returning an array so you can't do `[0]`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById

By the way, look into jQuery.

Comment: How is this jQuery related? His teacher obviously doesn't teach jQuery. By the way, look into Haskell.

Comment: @JanTuroň I didn't say it was jQuery-related, it was just a tip. With jQuery this would be much easier. But I answered his question.

Comment: just learning JavaScript is hard enough with this teacher not really teaching us anything, ill wait for the JQuery ... lol

Comment: @user3335267 Trust me, jQuery makes everything so much easier! It's just a library, it's not an entirely different language.

Answer (score 0):

In native javascript:

```
document.getElementById("caveboy").src = caveboyanim[curCaveBoy].src;
```

In jQuery you can do like this to get real DOM object:

```
$("#caveboy")[0].src = caveboyanim[curCaveBoy].src;
```

`document.getElementById("caveboy")` same as `$("#caveboy")[0]`